# Rmarkdown Kable with custom background colors knits successfully, but fails when called from render

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I have written an Rmarkdown file that loads some data and generates a kableExtra table with some symbols and custom colors and lines, printing it to pdf.

It works when I open the Rmarkdown file and knit, and produces the exact output that I want. For various reasons I need to call this Rmarkdown file from another .R file.

However, when I do this (using the rmarkdown::render function), I get an error that doesn't occur when knitted directly from within the .Rmd file. Specifically, the errors are caused by setting `background` within the `cell_spec` function; removing this call to set the background color allows me to successfully render the .Rmd file from another file. The error is:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
<to be read again> 
                   f
l.111 ...; background-color: #ffe6e6;" >1</span>}}
                                                  \\
```

Thanks so much for any advise.
Here is a complete Rmd file that reproduces the issue. The output when knitted directly from Rmd looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code.

````
---
title: ""
always_allow_html: yes
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=0.3in
header-includes:
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
- \usepackage{makecell}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \setmainfont{Helvetica}
- \pagenumbering{gobble}
- \DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{TU}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
documentclass: article
classoption: a4paper
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}

# Packages
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressMessages(library(extrafont))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressMessages(library(pander))
suppressMessages(library(kableExtra))

# Data
table_dat <- data.frame(latex_symbol = c("", "$\\blacktriangle$",
                                     "$\\blacklozenge$", "$\\blacklozenge$",
                                     "$\\bullet$", "+"),
                    color = c("#0c0000", "#ffde71", "#cb6f86",
                              "#0c0000", "#0c0000", "#0c0000"),
                    name = c("Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Thing 3",
                             "Thing 4", "Thing 5", "Thing 6"),
                    latex_font_size = c(14, 11, 8, 11, 16, 8),
                    value = c(1,"<0",3,4,5,6),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

fsize <- 12

bgcolor <- c(rep("#ffe6e6",2), rep("#ffffff", 4))
table_dat$value <- cell_spec(table_dat$value, background = bgcolor)

  ktable <- table_dat %>%
    rename(color_ = color) %>%
    mutate(latex_symbol = cell_spec(latex_symbol, color = color_,
                                font_size = latex_font_size,
                                escape = FALSE,
                              format = "latex")) %>%
    select(latex_symbol, name, value) %>%
    kable(escape = FALSE, align = rep("l", 3),
      booktabs = TRUE, format = "latex",
      col.names = c("Symbol", "Name", "Value"),
      linesep = "") %>%
    row_spec(1:6, color = "darkgray") %>%
    row_spec(0, bold = TRUE) %>%
    column_spec(1, "5em") %>%
    column_spec(2, "11em") %>%
    column_spec(3, "4em") %>%
    kable_styling(font_size = fsize) %>% 
    row_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    row_spec(1:4, hline_after = TRUE)

    ```

 ```{r, echo=FALSE}
 ktable
 ```
````

Note: the reason for so many packages being cited explicitly in the header is that I've had issues similar to this in the past that were solved by citing all of the packages associated with `kable` in my header before rendering. However, that didn't seem to solve my problem this time.

Comment: I'm away from my computer now but I just realized the issue is probably that cell_spec isn't specifying format=latex.

Comment: Yep... that fixed it... d'oh

Comment: which version of `kableExtra` are you using? Cuz with 0.9, you won't need to type "latex" in cell_spec. I'm just curious if using the render function also disabled this functionality.